# Passing PHP variables onclick

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Say I have two files, `fileone.php` and `filetwo.php`.

`fileone.php` generates a list of links, items from a mySQL database, every one of these items have an unique integer ID (1,2,3,4...).

`filetwo.php` contains a PHP function that uses this ID to create a page displaying the item you clicked in `fileone.php`. Depending on what item you click in `fileone.php` you will see a different image, text and more in `filetwo.php`.

My problem:
How do I at all send the ID from `fileone.php` to `filetwo.php`? Do I use forms with the $_GET variable? This is purely a hypothetical situation and I have no code to show, I just need input on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could just pass the ID via $_GET

fileone.php...

```
<a href="/filetwo.php?id=1">1</a>
<a href="/filetwo.php?id=2">2</a>
<a href="/filetwo.php?id=3">3</a>
```

filetwo.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    //do somethign with $_GET['id']
}
```

You should look into PDO or mysqli to receive and sanitize the input. do NOT use mysql_ functions as they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use `$_GET` variable.
Your HTML code in `fileone.php` will look something like this:

```
<a href="filetwo.php?itemId=1">Item 1</a>
<a href="filetwo.php?itemId=2">Item 2</a>
<a href="filetwo.php?itemId=3">Item 3</a>
```

And in `filetwo.php` you get itemId value with `$_GET['itemId']` and output image, text, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depdending on the sensitivity of the information and wether you care if users may alter the address to see a different id or not, you would use $_GET, otherwise $_POST, and if you are dealing with very sensitive stuff like user states or a shopping cart, then use $_SESSION.

So, for $_GET you would have a link to filetwo.php?id=3

Over on filetwo.php you would connect to the database based on $_GET['id'] and develop your view like that.